# iPhone X has a green line on the screen. What is damaged?

Tags: iphone, display, hardware

After dropping my iPhone X, green lines appeared on the screen (attached image). Searching for the problem online I could not find a satisfying answer. I would like to know if this is clearly a display (or display cable) issue, or if it might be a graphic driver/chip problem; E.g., Can I solve the problem with "simply" replacing the display.

I am assuming that there is no guaranteed answer to this, however, any best guess or with high probability answer would help me deciding the fate of my phone :)

[image]

---

**NOTE** I did a repair myself, solution added as separate answer.

Comment: It would be best if you edited your solution into an existing answer or just made an answer. Other people may not notice your solution posted as an edit to the question. I sincerely appreciate you coming back with an update, just the site works best with all the answers in the answer section..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like a hardware issue, display or cable hard to tell, but I'd guess display itself.

A quick test to make sure it's not earlier in the structure is take a screenshot & look at it on another machine, phone, pad, computer. The line won't be there in the screenshot if it's a hardware fail after the GPU.

Comment: Thanks, yes screenshot works fine. Touch at the green line also seems to work. Since the cables to the screen are part of the replacement screen module anyway I guess I have a high chance of solving the problem by replacing it, right?

Comment: I've never taken any iPhone apart myself, so I really don't know on that score, sorry.

Comment: AASP-certified: Yes, a display replacement will also include all the attendant cabling, and even fresh screws! There is a very, very minimal chance there's an issue with the MLB or the ZIF port, but that's highly unlikely from the factory, and you've given no indication that anyone's been inside the phone.

Comment: Its not particularly easy to replace however. There will be glue pads that you need to heat up(Hairdryer or heat gun) enough to melt in order to get the old screen out and then youll have to replace those with new glue pads when you put the new screen in.

Comment: I guess there's also a very small chance that the display connector just needs reseating? (I've changed screens on a 4S and a 6, but never been near an X).

Comment: From what I've seen, next to getting the screen and an adhesive that seals the phone when closing. To keep the TrueTone capability one has to load/burn some screen settings from the old to the new display with an additional device.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, as a former Apple Authorised Service Provider, this issue often appears together with multi-touch issues on the iPhone X and comes down to the display unit. There is a [repair program](https://support.apple.com/iphone-x-display-module-replacement-program) for iPhone X devices with touch issues.

I'd suggest a visit to the Apple Store or an Apple Authorised Service Provider and see if they can perform the repair under the program or otherwise perhaps wait a little bit until the issue occurs (again, in my experience, it most likely will do so, if only intermittently) and get it replaced then.

> Opinion: I'd advise against replacing the display yourself on an
>   iPhone X (or any (splash-) waterproof iPhone for that matter) unless
>   you really know what you're doing since not only is opening it a pain,
>   but so is resealing it properly. Apart from the fact that it's very
>   hard to get decent replacement parts.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I replaced quit a few things on previous generation iPhones (with success). Yes, I saw the replacement program, however, I do not have a touch problem and the green-lines are permanent.

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question and here follows my solution:

I replaced the display myself. Doing so, I noticed why the display got damaged. The battery was swollen up and pressed against the display. So I also replaced the battery. Now (almost) everything works. Since I did (at the time) not find much videos about this topic I made a video of the repair, note: tech videos are not my thing.

Youtube [video of my repair](https://youtu.be/s3XCsY5T2Nc).